# With remesh tool in Meshmixer; What happens to the details of the model?

Tags: stl, meshmixer

I have an organic but more complex STL model. It is so detailed and every detail is important to us.

We have a remesh tool in Meshmixer. It says:

> With Meshmixer, you can create an even tessellation using the Remesh command. Click the Select Icon in the menu and click to create an area to be remeshed, or use Ctrl + A to select the entire object. On the Popup menu, click Edit → Remesh or hit R.

Question:
When applying this tool to my STL model, does it happen that any detail will be gone off? Or, will I get same complex model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While doing this, you may encounter the loss of details. To avoid this, precise settings must be made. For example,

- Adaptive Size: This option can be used to configure large surfaces and preserve small details.
- Detail Smoothing :With this process, a more detailed examination of the surface is checked. This option must be enabled.
- Target Triangle Count:It is used to increase the number of triangles that will divide the surface as the mesh operation is repeated. Using this, the more triangles we can cover the surface, the more detailed information can be obtained.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for helping and contributing to the site. Unfortunately, some of your suggested edits were rejected as they actually changed, or removed, parts of the OP's question, or removed things that, while weren't strictly necessary, did no harm in being there. Admittedly, editing can be a bit of a fine art. However, looking for things to edit in old posts, on a small site such as this, will be fruitless as most posts have already been reviewed by many in the community already. Checking new posts is the best option, as these will not have been reviewed much yet..

Comment: If you need some tips, please read this post on our "meta" site: [Useful things to check for when cleaning up posts](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/500/4762)

Comment: Furthermore, if too many of your edits are rejected the SE system will think you are deliberately sabotaging the system and you will get a temporary ban. Please read the shared link from @Greenonline in the previous comment if you want to help us out tidying up the site.